# How to install a custom widget in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have extended QListView to override its mouse events, and I wish to make that extension available as a widget on the Qt Creator visual design Widget Box.

I am following the analog clock example of building a custom widget. I managed to build it without errors. But how do I install it? Do I add a build step and append "install" to the make command?

The Qt docs merely mention, like, oh you could install just it or make install, without clearly explaining how to install a custom widget. How do I do a "make install" inside project build

In .NET, i.e. visual studio window forms, all I had to do was include the widget in my project.

Do I have to manually copy the .so or .dll files to a particular directory?

Could someone give me a succinct discrete clear explanation what I need to do to get the custom widget to appear in my Qt Creator widget box? I am not asking about how to write code and configuration to create a custom widget. I already have a custom widget. I just need to know what my next step should be.

I am using Ubuntu, so don't indulge in explaining why/how rebuild Creator on mingw for Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an easier approach. Just place a normal QListView in designer, right click, and "promote to". There, enter a classname for your extended widget.

Comment: Yes, in most cases that's sufficient.

Comment: +1 Very very easy workaround (after I've spent hours trying to make custom plugin which ends up with failure). This still doesn't let the custom widgets appear on "widgets pane" (the pane that visualize available widgets on Qt Designer) but once custom widgets have been promoted they seem to be promotable in the future.

Comment: It is not a good idea to do that. Because you cannot see the properties of the custom widget on the Qt form designer. The best approach is to use "Plugins".

Answer (score 1):

To use widget you only need include its module to project.
To see widget in designer, you need to write plugin for qt designer.

I used cmake and linux, but I suppose this is also simmilar for other setups.
In CMakeLists.txt I have:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(widgets_plugin SHARED
  foo.cpp
)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(widgets_plugin PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${QT_DEFINITIONS} -DQDESIGNER_EXPORT_WIDGETS -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_SHARED")

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(widgets_plugin ${QT_LIBRARIES})
IF (NOT WIN32)
  ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(TARGET widgets_plugin POST_BUILD
      COMMAND rm -fr ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/designer
      COMMAND mkdir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/designer
      COMMAND cp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libwidgets_plugin.so ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/designer/
 )
ENDIF (NOT WIN32)
```

After that you need define enviroment variable

```
 QT_PLUGIN_PATH="path/to/you/plugin"
```

and run qt designer in such way that it see this variable.

As I remember there is strange behaviour of qt designer on non windows machine: it not look at QT_PLUGIN_PATH, but use $QT_PLUGIN_PATH/designer, while on windows it looks at $QT_PLUGIN_PATH.